# WooCommerce back to store after payment get -1

Tags: woocommerce, gateway

I have a problem with last step into payment process with my gateway.
I have a class:

```
class ECC_Payment_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
    public $id;
    public $merchantID;

    ....

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> id = 'ecc';
        $this -> action_url = ....

        ....

        $this -> init_form_fields();
        $this -> init_settings();

        ....

        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id,  array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
        add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_' . $this->id,                           array($this, 'check_ipn_response'));
        add_action('woocommerce_receipt_' . $this->id,                          array($this, 'generate_form'));
        add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id,                         array($this, 'thankyou_page'));
        add_action('template_redirect', 'ecc_redirect_after_purchase' );
        add_action('woocommerce_api_callback', 'callback_handler' );
        add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'ecc_add_to_cart_redirect');

    }
}
```

I defined all of add_actions-functions, but when my gateway makes redirect, no one had been fired. 
My Gateway send response to my store with all parameters (order_id, amount etc.) into POST body.
But I get only a page with -1 into content.

I tried several ways for redirect/notify url on my gateway (because I have a couple of examples):

- as php class (actually as it described into WC Docs)::

  http://[my_store_place]/?wc-api=ECC_Payment_Gateway

  http://[my_store_place]/wc-api/ECC_Payment_Gateway
- as plugin id:

  http://[my_store_place]/?wc-api=ecc

  http://[my_store_place]/wc-api/ecc

I'm a little bit confused with order of actions

Am I right that WC *should intercept such request from gateway*, ***automatically*** parse parameters and redirect me 
from checkout page:

```
http://[my_store_place]/checkout/?key=wc_order_5a575e004be9a&order=184
```

to another page (thankyou-page) with parsed orderID?

```
http://[my_store_place]/checkout/order-received/184/?key=wc_order_5a575e004be9a
```

184 - order_id for gateway
5a575e004be9a - order_id for db (as i understand)

Or i have to do any additional manual steps to prosess request from my gateway to my webstore?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What payment gateway are you using? Also, when you say `when my gateway makes redirect`, do you mean when the payment gateway, like Paypal, redirects back to your website after you confirm your purchase? Or are you talking about the IPN payment confirmation from Paypal?

Comment: Yes, the 1st. I have my local payment gateway (not PayPal) that makes POST request back to my store after payment had been confirmed on it. As i understand from off WC docs, an url must be in form http://[my_store_place]/wc-api/ECC_Payment_Gateway (for WC version > 2.0). I don't understand why my hooks don't fire. I form url from gateway as it described in off docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc_api-the-woocommerce-api-callback/